# Multiple definition of a function error in C++ file

Tags: c++, codeblocks

I added a certain file to my Code::Blocks C++ project which takes an input of a `struct` and returns an output of `struct`. However, when I add those two functions, I start getting the error:

```
/src/Converter.h|23|multiple definition of `Converters::ColorConverters::RGB_to_HSV(Converters::ColorConverters::RGBColor)'|
```

The code in the file is as follows:

```
#ifndef CONVERTERS_H
#define CONVERTERS_H

#define MIN3(x,y,z)  ((y) <= (z) ? ((x) <= (y) ? (x):(y)) : ((x) <= (z) ? (x):(z)))
#define MAX3(x,y,z)  ((y) >= (z) ? ((x) >= (y) ? (x):(y)) : ((x) >= (z) ? (x):(z)))

namespace Converters
{
    namespace ColorConverters
    {
    struct RGBColor{
        float r,g,b;
    };

    struct HSVColor{
        float hue, sat, val;
    };
        struct HSVColor RGB_to_HSV(struct RGBColor rgb){
        }
        struct RGBColor HSV_to_RGB(struct HSVColor hsv){
        }
    }
}
#endif // CONVERTER_H
```

And include this in one of my other class with `#include "Converter.h"`. Any suggestions what's going wrong and how to get rid of this error.

Comment: You have defined this function somewhere else as well. Btw you can omit the `struct` before the return types.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both of these:

```
    struct HSVColor RGB_to_HSV(struct RGBColor rgb)
    {
    }
    struct RGBColor HSV_to_RGB(struct HSVColor hsv)
    {
    }
```

Are being defined in your header file. You want them *declared* (like the one right above), and *defined* in a .cpp source file.

**Header**:

```
#ifndef CONVERTERS_H
#define CONVERTERS_H

#define MIN3(x,y,z)  ((y) <= (z) ? ((x) <= (y) ? (x):(y)) : ((x) <= (z) ? (x):(z)))
#define MAX3(x,y,z)  ((y) >= (z) ? ((x) >= (y) ? (x):(y)) : ((x) >= (z) ? (x):(z)))

namespace Converters
{
    namespace ColorConverters
    {
        struct RGBColor{
            float r,g,b;
        };

        struct HSVColor{
            float hue, sat, val;
        };

        HSVColor RGB_to_HSV(RGBColor rgb);
        RGBColor HSV_to_RGB(HSVColor hsv);
    }
}
```

**Source**:

```
Converters::ColorConverters::HSVColor 
 Converters::ColorConverters::RGB_to_HSV(RGBColor rgb)
{
    .. code here..
}

Converters::ColorConverters::RGBColor 
 Converters::ColorConverters::HSV_to_RGB(HSVColor hsv)
{
    .. code here ..
};
```

Alternatively you can inline them in the header-only if desired:

**Header**:

```
#ifndef CONVERTERS_H
#define CONVERTERS_H

#define MIN3(x,y,z)  ((y) <= (z) ? ((x) <= (y) ? (x):(y)) : ((x) <= (z) ? (x):(z)))
#define MAX3(x,y,z)  ((y) >= (z) ? ((x) >= (y) ? (x):(y)) : ((x) >= (z) ? (x):(z)))

namespace Converters
{
    namespace ColorConverters
    {
        struct RGBColor{
            float r,g,b;
        };

        struct HSVColor{
            float hue, sat, val;
        };

        inline HSVColor RGB_to_HSV(RGBColor rgb)
        {
            .. code here ..
        };

        inline RGBColor HSV_to_RGB(HSVColor hsv)
        {
            .. code here ..
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: Either that or make them `inline`.

Comment: @Kos that would be the bottom of the answer, in case you stopped reading it.

Comment: I stopped because I hit EOF; it was a bit shorter when I had commented.

Comment: @Kos it was? there is a 4min-lapse between last edit and your comment. browser refresh ouch. =p